# Empty string not getting written with RawConfigParser

Tags: python, merge, ini, configparser

I'm copying sections and options and values from one `.ini` file to another in order to merge multiple `.ini` files into one, with [RawConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser).

In one source `.ini` I have this and would like it to be copied:

```
[foo]
bar=""
```

However, the result I got is

```
[foo]
bar=
```

this fails my requirement because the closed external program I test won't work with this ini.

I've tried with `'""'`, `\"\"`, `"\"\""` but without success. (**edit**: note that in the output `''` won't do any good for me either, it *needs* to be `""`)

My code is:

```
import ConfigParser

inireader = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
inireader.read('source.ini')

iniwriter=ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
for section_name in inireader.sections():
    for name, value in inireader.items(section_name):
        print name,value
        if not iniwriter.has_section(section_name):
            iniwriter.add_section(section_name)
        iniwriter.set(section_name, name, value)
with open("output.ini", "wb") as f:
    iniwriter.write(f)
```

`if value == "": iniwriter.set(section_name,name,'""')` works, but is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Is there a non-hackish way to do this?

**edit**: I'm using *Python 2.7*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the [ConfigParser source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8d5df9602a72/Lib/ConfigParser.py#l529), it looks like there is a special case where the `read()` function will convert two double quotes as a value to an empty string.

Not exactly sure why that decision was made, but it is definitely intentional behavior and I think that you will need to go with your hacky `if value == "":  iniwriter.set(section_name,name,'""')` to work around this.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Unexpected from a ***Raw***ConfigParser, and even without an option to turn it off. Thanks for digging it up!